# button is jumping when using bootstrap tooltip on bootbox.dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap tool-tip for button on boot-box dialog but when i hover the button it is jumping then and I've tried "container","append to" attribute too but it is not working at all .

```
$('input[type="button"]').tooltip('destroy');
$('input[type="button"]').tooltip({
    'trigger': 'hover', 
    container: 'input[type="button"]'
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?